# Check if file exists with Laravel 5.5 Storage? Storage for Avatar

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-5.5, file-exists

Based on this code: https://devdojo.com/episode/laravel-user-image I created the following code in order to upload an avatar and delete the old one. I'm tried to use Storage:Facade but I'm not sure if it is the right way. So let's look at my code excerpt:

```
                    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
                    ..

                    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');

                    $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();      

                    //Using Image intervention, storing to Public/Images/user
                    Image::make($avatar)->orientate()->fit(220)->save( public_path('/images/user/' . $filename ) );
                    $user = Auth::user();

                    $oldavatar = $user->avatar;

                    $user->avatar = $filename;
                    $user->save();

                    //Delete old avatar
                    if($oldavatar != 'profile.jpg' and Storage::disk('public')->exists('/images/user/' . $oldavatar );){

                        Storage::disk('public')->delete('/images/user/' . $oldavatar );
                    }
```

So I tested it out with dd(Storage::disk('public')->exists('index.php')); etc. I tried every file there is. I also added a disk in the filesystem.php with

```
    'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Still nothing, I'm getting a false for exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future readers:

```
                   //e.g. user/hashMD5.jpg
                    $filename = $avatar->hashName('user');

                    $image = Image::make($avatar)->orientate()->fit(220);

                    $location = Storage::disk('images')->put($filename, (string) $image->encode());

                    if($location){
                        $user = Auth::user();

                        $oldfilename = $user->avatar;                           

                        $oldfileexists = Storage::disk('images')->exists( $oldfilename );

                        //Delete old avatar
                        if($oldfilename != 'user/profile.jpg' and $oldfileexists){
                            Storage::disk('images')->delete( $oldfilename );
                        }  

                        //Save current image to database. Sollte ich nicht update benutzen?
                        $user->avatar = $filename;
                        $user->update();
                    }
```

With the filesystem.php:

```
        'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: thanks for coming back and putting the right answer! your solution worked @PhilippMochine

Answer (score 0):

`public_path()` and the disk 'public' don't have the same root.

The public disk is probably pointing to something like: `.../yoursite/storage/app/public`

`public_path()` would return something like: `.../yoursite/public`

The public disk is linked to the public folder at `.../yoursite/public/storage` -> `.../yoursite/storage/app/public`